# How can I get this chart to display next to data table in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, google-visualization

Please refer to this jsfiddle: [Google chart API example](http://jsfiddle.net/s4sm3/2/)

Is there something obvious this CSS that reveals how I can get the chart to display to the right of the  data table instead of below it? Or is the chart location being controlled by the Javascript? Can you please provide a solution? I tried various CSS methods to split chart from the data table with no luck.

The chart does display in my browser but I couldn't get it to work in the jsfiddle.

**(P.S. The Javascript is in the jsfiddle above--it's pretty lengthy...)**

Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/attc.googleCharts.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cs/attcSandbox.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="mainContent">
        <table class="left"
            title="Attendance Percentages" 
            id="AttendancePercentages" 
            summary="pieDescription" 
            data-attc-createChart="true"
            data-attc-colDescription="pieDescription" 
            data-attc-colValues="pieValues" 
            data-attc-location="AttendancePercentagesPie" 
            data-attc-hideTable="true" 
            data-attc-type="pie"
            data-attc-googleOptions='{"is3D":true}'
            data-attc-controls='{"showHide":true,"create":true,"chartType":true}'
            >
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th id="pieDescription">Description</th>
                    <th id="pieValues">Sessions</th>
                    <th>%</th>
                    <th>Other</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Present</td>
                    <td>405</td>
                    <td>89</td>
                    <td>5</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Missing</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Authorised Absent</td>
                    <td>36</td>
                    <td>7</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Unauthorised Absent</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Late</td>
                    <td>30</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="right" id="AttendancePercentagesPie"></div>
        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
/* @media screen { */
/* override css in main */
body{
    margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px;
    margin-top:5px;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    z-index:0;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    color:#47535E;
    font-size:0.7em;
    font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
}

div.left {
    border: 2px solid #CFBFAF;
    width: 49%;
    float: left;
}

div.right {
    border: 2px solid #CFBFAF;
    width: 49%;
    float: right;
}

div.mainContent{
    margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 20px;
    width:400px;
}
table{
    margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;
    width:98%;
    border:1px solid #E6E6E6;
    border-radius:5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color:#F6F6F6;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td,table th{
    border:1px solid #E6E6E6;
    border-top:1px solid #FFFFFF;
}
table th{
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
/*attc classes*/
/*attc classes*/
div.attcControls{
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid #E6E6E6;
    border-radius:5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color:#F6F6F6;
}
div.attcControls ul{
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:2px 2px 2px 2px;
    margin:0px;
}
div.attcControls ul li{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 10px;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
    float:right;
    clear:none;
}
div.attcControls ul li a{
    border:1px solid #9CDFF7;
    border-radius:3px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color:#86D6F5;
    padding:2px;
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:inline-block;
    background-image:none;
    font-weight:normal;
}
div.attcControls ul li a:hover{
    border:1px solid white;
    color:#47535E;
}
div.attcControls ul li fieldset{
    border:1px solid #9CDFF7;
    border-radius:3px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color:#86D6F5;
    padding:2px;
    margin:0px;
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
}
div.attcControls ul li fieldset label{
    padding-right:5px;  
}
div.attcControls ul li fieldset select{
    font-size:1em;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}

input.attcEditCheckRadioBoxes{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
/* } */
```

([Source code link here](https://code.google.com/p/auto-table-to-chart/) under [Apache 2.0 license](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things first of all you are specifying div.left therefore the class on table never inherits any properties from it's class name of left. Secondly table has a width of 98% that means it is going to take up pretty much it's whole block and force all content above or below. Ideally you would want the right and left classes to apply with the widths at 49% you should be ok the borders add 2px left and right equaling a total of 4px per container and should in essence come out to 1% in your 400px wide .mainContent area some browsers may not respect this size perfectly so you may have to reduce the widths slightly to accommodate the borders.

Comment: Zanderi, thank you kindly for your time and consideration. For some reason, I'm finding CSS harder to learn than Python, PHP, and Javascript... Removing the 98% table width nailed it and now, in retrospect, it makes total sense. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [modified JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s4sm3/4/) where I managed to get it to float to the right of the table.

In short I added this to your css:

```
.right{
    float: right;
    width: 40%;
}
.left{
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
}
```

and removed the fixed width (98%) from your tabled.

I would also recommend making the mainbody much wider to fit the two of them, note that if the content inside the right floated element is a big block element (like a chart) it may blow out (either to go beneath the table or outside the mainbody).

(if you are using bootstrap, or there was another reason for the .right and .left classes due to a framework, please consider making a separate class for the fixed 40% and 60% widths, or use the built in spans)

Comment: Benjamin, thank you very much for your time and consideration. Creating a wider body and removing the 98% fixed table width nailed it. Thanks again. 

P.S. The .right and .left that was in my code that didn't have an accompanying class in the CSS was a remnant from a prior failed experiment that I forgot to take out in my post. So at one point I was on the right track--I just needed your expertise to get there all the way. :)